# spring.threads.virtual.enabled does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am going through this [article](https://www.danvega.dev/blog/virtual-threads-spring-boot) regarding enabling Virtual Threads in Spring boot application

My application uses JDK21, Spring boot 3.2.2, but although I put this in my application.yaml file

```
spring:
  threads:
    virtual:
      enabled: true
```

I am not able to see the described in the article log(no Thread words at all in the console) that shows me that the Virtual threads are enabled.

```
2023-12-14T09:39:27.943-05:00  INFO 12176 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] d.d.h.HttpBinController                  : 200 OK on Thread[#38,http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main]
```

I would highly appreciate it if somebody could share what can be a problem or is there any other way that I can check if they are enabled?

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, @AndyWilkinson Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to share what exactly can help you with the investigation?

Comment: A Git repo or similar of all of the code and build configuration that's required to reproduce the problem. You must have done something differently to the article that you are following otherwise it would be working as expected. Without seeing what you've done, we can't tell what those differences might be.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a test project and it's confidential, so I am not able to deploy it in any public place. I will try to find out way/time to play around with removing things  and see if will have some success but based on the article things should be straightforward in case I use the JDK21 with Spring boot 3.2.X, I mean there are no specific configurations that can be done in a wrong way